# How to Get Actual Hard Disk Memory of A VM?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

Is it possible to get the actual hard disk usage of a virtual machine?

```
Measure-VM -Name * | select-object -property TotalDiskAllocation
```

The TotalDiskAllocation property gets the total disk space assigned to the VM and even though this is helpful I also need to know how much is really being used.

For example, if a VM has 150 GB of allocated memory and it only uses 50 GB, is there any Powershell command that will be able to extract the 50 GB? If yes, how will I be able to incorporate that script to the script above?

Comment: What do you mean by 'really being used'? Are the disks thin provisioned? Do you mean what the guest OS is using inside the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your attempt to use Measure-VM, I assumed you are using Hyper-V. I use something similar to this in one of my Hyper-V scripts:

```
(Get-VM dechiro1).HardDrives | ForEach {
    $GetVhd = Get-VHD -Path $_.Path
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Type = $GetVhd.VhdType
        ProvisionedGB = ($GetVhd.Size / 1GB)
        CommittedGB = ($GetVhd.FileSize / 1GB)
    }
}
```

Basically, for each of the virtual machine's hard drives, use Get-VHD to get the VHD details which includes the full size and what I refer to as the committed size (actual space on disk).

Example output:

```
Name                                                   Type                 ProvisionedGB                   CommittedGB
----                                                   ----                 -------------                   -----------
Hard Drive on IDE controll...                       Dynamic                            20                    0.00390625
Hard Drive on IDE controll...                       Dynamic                            40                    0.00390625
```

**Edit**:

If you wanted to pull from every VM and include the VM name with the returned object and you prefer to use the pipeline form, this will work:

```
Get-VM | ForEach { $Vm = $_; $_.HardDrives } | ForEach {
    $GetVhd = Get-VHD -Path $_.Path
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Vm = $Vm.Name
        Name = $_.Name
        Type = $GetVhd.VhdType
        ProvisionedGB = ($GetVhd.Size / 1GB)
        CommittedGB = ($GetVhd.FileSize / 1GB)
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I need to get the details of all the VMs?

Comment: I just updated with an example of running against every VM and including the VM name in the output. If you don't like the nested foreach in the pipeline form, I can post an example of using the 'normal' foreach loop which I personally prefer for cases like this where you are nesting loops.